# Binding multiple expressions in custom attributes

Tags: aurelia

I am having trouble binding multiple expressions in Aurelia custom attributes. I am posting this because I have been struggling and I believe that the documentation might be missing something (?). Hopefully it is not some stupid thing that I missed so that more people will have use of this aswell.

This is my simplified implementation.

**resultCustomAttribute.js**

```
import {inject, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
export class resultCustomAttribute {
    @bindable foo;
    @bindable bar;
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
        console.log(this.foo); // => null
        console.log(this.bar); // => null
    }
    fooChanged(value){
        console.log(value) // Does not run
    }
}
```

**main.js**

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .feature('resources'); // resources is a folder in the source root
                                  with an index.js file that sets my custom
                                  attribute as a globalResource 

    aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```

**home.html**

```
<template>
    .
    .
    .
    <div repeat.for="item of items"> <!-- items is an array of objects in home.js-->
        <h4>${item.title}</h4>
        <div result="foo.bind: item.foo; bar.bind: item.bar">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
</template>
```

The problem is that whatever I bind foo and bar too, they become `null` in my custom attribute. the element is however passed to the resultCustomAttribute correctly. Is my implementation correct or am I missing something?

**EDIT:** The above implementation seems to be correct after all. When I simplified my code to provide a general purpose question, I removed the camelCase named variable `selectionIndex` and replaced it with `bar` as seen above. This caused the `selectionIndexChanged` function not to run.

And the reson that `this.foo` and `this.bar` are null in the contructor is simply because the constructor is run before the values are changed for the first time.

Comment: what happens if you add the following method to your custom attribute class:
`bind(bindingContext) {
  console.log(this.foo);
  console.log(this.bar);
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit embarrasing. After asking this question suddenly the `foo` variable started to work, and I couldn't find how to reproduce my original problem. `fooChanged` ran correctly but my `barChanged` still did not run at all.

This is because the `bar`variable is not actually named bar in my real code, It is a variable with camelCase naming `selectionIndex`. When using camelCase naming aurelia did not hook my `selectionIndexChanged` correctly. I changed it to `selectionindex` and `selectionindexChanged` and now both variables are bound as they should.

Sorry for waste of space. But maybe this will be useful for someone.

**EDIT**
see comment by shunty for explanation on how to use camelCase in custom attributes

Comment: I've been foiled by this one too. Took me ages to realise that in the HTML the attribute binding should be to 'selection-index' and in the js code the variable should be 'selectionIndex' (as you had it). You should find that selectionIndexChanged will work then. Still catches me almost every time!